# XAML databind with conditions

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

In a project for windows phone 8 , i have a List<> of objects of this type.

```
 public class Media
{
    public string idNews { get; set; }
    public string video_url { get; set; }
    public string idMenu { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public string video_image { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }

}
```

i then bind that list to a XAML

MediaScroll.DataContext = media.listaMedia;
and in my XAML i have

```
<ScrollViewer  Name="MediaScroll" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <ItemsControl  Name="ItControl" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate2}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ItemsPanelTemplate1}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
```

and

```
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate2">

        <StackPanel Width="480">
            <Image Name="overlay" Source="/Assets/play@2x.png" Width="75" Canvas.ZIndex="10" Margin="203,85,202,0"  />
            <Image Tag="{Binding id}" Source="{Binding image}" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,-160,0,0" Tap="Image_Tap" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

my question is , how can i bind either image or video_image depending on witch on ins't empty, also , how can i make " Image Name="overlay" " only display if the other image is bound with a video_image

Answer (score 0):

Inside your StackPanel, create only one Image control that has the Source set up with a Binding image.

Create a [Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and attach that to your Binding to programatically return either your play@2x.png as an ImageSource or your image.

Comment: each of my objects has a video_image and image fields, and one of them will be empty, so i have to use the other one to do the binding. i can achieve that with the Converter?

Comment: Sure, have your converter bind directly to your Media object like this:
    Source="{Binding, Converter={StaticResource MediaConverter}"

where 'Binding' on its own will reference your item

Comment: any chance you could give me an example?, having some problems getting it to work